# Trouble Loading Multiple Models in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

In our project, we have a set of 13 models, comprising two metro stations and eleven viaducts that link these stations. These models have been loaded into the Forge Viewer with the assistance of Revit shared coordinates. While the loading process proceeds smoothly for 12 of these models, we are encountering a significant challenge with one specific model, which happens to be the second metro station in our sequence. This particular model does not load into its intended shared coordinate position.

To provide you with more context, our model positioning follows a pattern: it begins with a metro station, spans through eleven viaducts, and concludes with another metro station. The primary issue centers around the second metro station model.

In our pursuit of a solution, we have attempted various methods to load the model correctly and achieve the desired outcome. Specifically, we have experimented with commenting on the globalOffset parameter while loading the viaduct that connects to the metro station and  Interestingly, when we loaded the metro station model with the globalOffset parameter, without commenting, it appeared connected in the viewer as expected.
However, it's important to note that we cannot apply this particular format to the remaining models. Consistency is crucial, and we need to load each model in the same manner.

We are loading each model using the code below.

```
function LoadModel(viewer, urn) {

    debugger;

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {

            debugger;

            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getAecModelData(doc.getRoot()).then(function (aec) {

                //console.log('AEC metadata', aec);

                const rootItem = doc.getRoot();

                var filter;

                var viewables = rootItem.search({ type: 'geometry' });

                var modelviewGuid = viewables[0].data.guid;

                var globalOffset = viewer.model?.getData().globalOffset;

                if (aec) {

                    let tf = aec && aec.refPointTransformation;

                    if(tf){

                        let refPoint = tf ? { x: tf[9], y: tf[10], z: 0.0 } : { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };

 

                        const MaxDistSqr = 4.0e6;

                        const distSqr = globalOffset && THREE.Vector3.prototype.distanceToSquared.call(refPoint, globalOffset);

                        if (!globalOffset || distSqr > MaxDistSqr) {

                            globalOffset = new THREE.Vector3().copy(refPoint);

                        }

                    }

                }

                var options = {

                    keepCurrentModels: true,

                    //placementTransform: (new THREE.Matrix4()).setPosition({ x: 50, y: 0, z: -50 }),

                    globalOffset: globalOffset,

                    applyRefPoint: true,

                    isAEC: true,

                };

                resolve(viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables[0], options).then(

                function onLoadFinished(model) {

                    debugger;

                    viewer.setProgressiveRendering(false);

                        viewer.setQualityLevel(true, true);

                        viewer.setGroundShadow(false);

                        viewer.setGroundReflection(false);

                }));

            });

        }

        function onDocumentLoadFailure(code, message) {

            console.error('Could not load document.', message);

            reject(message);

        }

        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load('urn:' + urn, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

    });

}
```

We kindly request your guidance on the optimal solution for resolving this issue.

Comment: If just load two models, one is a model without this issue, and another one is the model encountering the issue, are they still misaligned? If yes, please open them in Revit Desktop to check the shared coordinate configs are correct.